How to write test class for httpcallout which is written in queueable interface
I have a class when QuoteAwsAccountId Object is created or AwsAccountId value inside the QuoteAwsAccountd object which is a string then it should make a get call to external api using Named credentials.
The api take list of AwsAccountId values and a returns list of Sor's values for a given AwsAccountId. I need to compare the sor values with entity short name field in seller of record field if the match happens then we need to createQuoteSorRecords where
PP_Quote_Seller_Of_Record__c sorRecord = new PP_Quote_Seller_Of_Record__c(
    Seller_Of_Record__c = sorMap.get(sorName).Id,
    Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c = awsAccountIdMap.get(accountId).Id
);

I am not able to write test case for http callout and createsorRecords. Can anyone please help with this
public with sharing class QuoteSorAwsIdHelper { 

    // Named Credentials
    public static final String NAMED_CREDENTIAL_SANDBOX = 'DataProviderService_Sandbox';
    public static final String NAMED_CREDENTIAL_PRODUCTION = 'DataProviderService_Prod';
    public static final String ATTRIBUTE = 'sellerOfRecordList';
    
    // Custom Exception for this class
    public class QuoteSorAwsIdException extends Exception {}

    /**
     * @description Handles AWS Account ID processing after insert
     * @param ctx: RecordContext containing newly inserted records
     */
    public static void getAwsAccountIdsAfterInsert(RecordContext ctx) {
        List<PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c> newRecords = (List<PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c>) ctx.newSObjects;
        List<String> awsAccountIds = new List<String>();
        
        for (PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c record : newRecords) {
            if (record.AWS_Account_Id__c != null) {
                awsAccountIds.add(record.AWS_Account_Id__c);
            }
        }
        
        if (!awsAccountIds.isEmpty()) {
            processAwsAccountIdsInBatches(awsAccountIds, newRecords);
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * @description Handles AWS Account ID processing after update
     * @param ctx: RecordContext containing updated records
     */
    public static void getAwsAccountIdsAfterUpdate(RecordContext ctx) {
        Set<SObjectField> fieldsToCheck = new Set<SObjectField> {
            PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c.AWS_Account_Id__c
        };
        List<PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c> changedRecords = (List<PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c>) ctx.getChangedRecords(fieldsToCheck);
        List<String> awsAccountIds = new List<String>();
        
        for (PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c record : changedRecords) {
            if (record.AWS_Account_Id__c != null) {
                awsAccountIds.add(record.AWS_Account_Id__c); 
            }
        }
        
        if (!awsAccountIds.isEmpty()) {
            processAwsAccountIdsInBatches(awsAccountIds, changedRecords);
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * @description Processes AWS Account IDs in batches
     * @param awsAccountIds: List of AWS Account IDs
     * @param newRecords: List of PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c records
     */
    public static void processAwsAccountIdsInBatches(List<String> awsAccountIds, List<PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c> newRecords) {
        Integer batchSize = 100;
        Integer numberOfBatches = (awsAccountIds.size() + batchSize - 1) / batchSize;
        
        for (Integer i = 0; i < numberOfBatches; i++) {
            List<String> batchIds = new List<String>();
            List<PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c> batchRecords = new List<PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c>();
            
            for (Integer j = 0; j < batchSize && (i * batchSize + j) < awsAccountIds.size(); j++) {
                batchIds.add(awsAccountIds[i * batchSize + j]);
                batchRecords.add(newRecords[i * batchSize + j]);
            }
            
            QueueableUtilities.enqueueJob(new QuoteSorAwsIdQueueable(batchIds, batchRecords));
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * @description Retrieves Seller of Record records based on short names
     * @param shortNames: List of short names for Seller of Record
     * @return List of Seller_Of_Record__c records
     */
    private static List<Seller_Of_Record__c> getSellerOfRecords(List<String> shortNames){
        List<Seller_Of_Record__c> sellerOfRecordList = SObjectSelectors.getInstance(Seller_Of_Record__c.SObjectType)
            .setFields(new Set<SObjectField>{ Seller_Of_Record__c.Id, Seller_Of_Record__c.Short_Name__c })
            .selectByCondition(
                QueryResult.bindQuery(
                    'Short_Name__c IN {0}',
                    new List<Object>{ shortNames }
                )
            );
        return sellerOfRecordList;
    }
    
       /**
         * @description Retrieves the named credential based on the environment
         * @return Named credential string
         */
        private static String getNamedCredential() {
            return Utility.IsSandbox ? NAMED_CREDENTIAL_SANDBOX : NAMED_CREDENTIAL_PRODUCTION;
        }
    
    // Queueable class to handle asynchronous processing
    public class QuoteSorAwsIdQueueable implements Queueable {
        
        private List<String> awsAccountIds;
        private List<PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c> quoteAwsAccountRecords;
        
        public QuoteSorAwsIdQueueable(List<String> awsAccountIds, List<PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c> quoteAwsAccountRecords) {
            this.awsAccountIds = awsAccountIds;
            this.quoteAwsAccountRecords = quoteAwsAccountRecords;
        }
        
        /**
         * @description Executes the Queueable job to perform HTTP callout
         * @param context: QueueableContext
         */
        public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
            makeHttpCallout(awsAccountIds);
        }
        
        /**
         * @description Makes HTTP callout to get AWS account details
         * @param awsAccountIds: List of AWS Account IDs
         */
        public void makeHttpCallout(List<String> awsAccountIds) {
            try {
                String namedCredential = getNamedCredential();
                System.debug('NamedCredential: ' + namedCredential);

                HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
                req.setMethod('GET');
                req.setEndpoint('callout:' + namedCredential);
                
                // Construct query parameters
                String queryParams = 'awsAccountIds=' + String.join(awsAccountIds, '&awsAccountIds=') + '&attributes=' + ATTRIBUTE;
                req.setEndpoint(req.getEndpoint() + '?' + queryParams);
                req.setTimeout(120000);
                
                System.debug('Endpoint with params: ' + req.getEndpoint());
                
                if (!Test.isRunningTest()) { 
                    Http http = new Http();
                    HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
                    System.debug('HttpResponse: ' + res.toString());
                    System.debug('--> ' + res.getStatus());
                    
                    if( res.getStatusCode() != 200 ) {
                        // there was a problem and server responded with something other than success
                        throw new QuoteSorAwsIdException(res.getBody());  
                     }
                    
                    System.debug('getAwsAccountDetails API response:' + res.getBody());
                    System.debug('getAwsAccountDetails API Status:' + res.getStatus());
                    System.debug('getAwsAccountDetails API StatusCode: ' + res.getStatusCode());
                   
                    createQuoteSorRecords(res.getBody());
                    
                 }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.debug('Exception in making HTTP callout: ' + ex.getMessage());
                Logger.logExceptions('QuoteSorAwsIdHelper','makeHttpCallout',ex);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        
        /**
         * @description Creates Quote Seller Of Record records from the API response
         * @param responseBody: Response body from the API callout
         */
        private void createQuoteSorRecords(String responseBody) {
            Map<String, Object> responseMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(responseBody);
            Map<String, Object> awsAccountDetails = (Map<String, Object>) responseMap.get('awsAccountDetails');

            if (awsAccountDetails != null && !awsAccountDetails.isEmpty()) {
                Map<String, PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c> awsAccountIdMap = new Map<String, PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c>();
                for (PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c record : quoteAwsAccountRecords) {
                    awsAccountIdMap.put(record.AWS_Account_Id__c, record);
                }

                List<PP_Quote_Seller_Of_Record__c> sorRecords = new List<PP_Quote_Seller_Of_Record__c>();

                for (String accountId : awsAccountDetails.keySet()) {
                    Map<String, Object> accountDetails = (Map<String, Object>) awsAccountDetails.get(accountId);
                    List<Object> sorList = (List<Object>) accountDetails.get('sellerOfRecordList');

                    if (sorList != null && !sorList.isEmpty()) {
                        List<String> stringSorList = new List<String>();
                        for (Object obj : sorList) {
                            stringSorList.add((String) obj);
                        }

                        List<Seller_Of_Record__c> sellerOfRecords = getSellerOfRecords(stringSorList);
                        if (sellerOfRecords != null && !sellerOfRecords.isEmpty()) {
                            Map<String, Seller_Of_Record__c> sorMap = new Map<String, Seller_Of_Record__c>();
                            for (Seller_Of_Record__c sor : sellerOfRecords) {
                                sorMap.put(sor.Short_Name__c, sor);
                            }

                            for (String sorName : stringSorList) {
                                if (sorMap.containsKey(sorName) && awsAccountIdMap.containsKey(accountId)) {
                                    PP_Quote_Seller_Of_Record__c sorRecord = new PP_Quote_Seller_Of_Record__c(
                                Seller_Of_Record__c = sorMap.get(sorName).Id,
                                Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c = awsAccountIdMap.get(accountId).Id
                                    );
                                    sorRecords.add(sorRecord);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (sorRecords != null && !sorRecords.isEmpty()) {
                    try {
                        Dml.doInsert(sorRecords);
                    } catch (DmlException e) {
                        System.debug('Error inserting PP_Quote_Seller_Of_Record__c records: ' + e.getMessage());
                        Logger.logExceptions('QuoteSorAwsIdHelper', 'createQuoteSorRecords', e);
                        throw e;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Test class
    @isTest
    static void testMakeHttpCallout() {
        List<PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c> awsAccountRecords = [SELECT Id, AWS_Account_Id__c FROM PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c];
        List<String> awsAccountIds = new List<String>();

        for (PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c record : awsAccountRecords) {
            awsAccountIds.add(record.AWS_Account_Id__c);
        }

        Test.startTest();
        // Create an instance of the queueable class and execute
        QuoteSorAwsIdHelper.QuoteSorAwsIdQueueable queueableInstance = new QuoteSorAwsIdHelper.QuoteSorAwsIdQueueable(awsAccountIds, awsAccountRecords);
        queueableInstance.makeHttpCallout(awsAccountIds);

        // Simulate callout response
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());

        Test.stopTest();

        // Verify that records were processed
        System.assert(true, 'No exceptions were thrown');
    }

    // Mock HttpResponseGenerator
    private class MockHttpResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock {
        public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
            HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.setBody('{"awsAccountDetails":{"000022444666":{"accountId":"000022444666","sellerOfRecordList":["AWS Inc."]},"073537884685":{"accountId":"073537884685","sellerOfRecordList":["AWS Europe"]}}}');
            res.setStatusCode(200);
            return res;
        }
    }
} 

I am trying to do this but its not working

What have you tried? Where, specifically, are you stuck? If you're running into an error message, you need to include it (and the stack trace) verbatim, just copy/paste. You can [edit] your question to add that additional information.

And are you sure that you're having an issue with setting up a test or a mock callout because it's in a Queueable? or is it more that the issue is you're trying to set up a mock callout for that named credential? The queueable aspect of this shouldn't be any/much different from if it were in normal (i.e. not async) code. You also have the callout wrapped inside of a if(!Test.isRunningTest()), which makes it impossible for any test to get in and actually make a (mocked) callout.

public class QuoteSorAwsIdHelperTest {
@testSetup
static void testSetup() {
    TestUserService.createUsers();


@DerekF I have edited the code according. Do you want me to remove Test.runningTest from the code

A few things jump out to me. 1) You need to create test data inside of your test class. By default, tests are isolated from the "real" data in your org (except for a handful of SObjects like User, Profile, etc... collectively known as "setup objects"). So if you don't do that, your query on PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c in your test method is going to return 0 rows. 2) You need to call Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator()); before you run queueableInstance.makeHttpCallout(awsAccountIds);

Can we directly call the makehttpcallout from queueable interface. I am also confused with creating mock response. Can you please help with it and also I need to take credentials based on the org. Once http callout is successful it should create quote sor records. Can you help with this @DerekF

Let's make this a bit more concise so we can properly test it
public class QuoteSorAwsIdQueueable implements Queueable {

  public void execute(QueueableContext context) {makeHttpCallout(awsAccountIds);}

  private void makeHttpCallout(List<String> awsAccountIds) {
    try {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setEndpoint('callout:' + getNamedCredential());
            
        // Construct query parameters
        String queryParams = 'awsAccountIds=' + String.join(awsAccountIds, '&awsAccountIds=') + '&attributes=' + ATTRIBUTE;
        req.setEndpoint(req.getEndpoint() + '?' + queryParams);
        req.setTimeout(120000);
            
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
                
        if( res.getStatusCode() != 200 ) {
           throw new QuoteSorAwsIdException(res.getBody());  
        }        
               
        createQuoteSorRecords(res.getBody());
                
     }
     catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.logExceptions('QuoteSorAwsIdHelper','makeHttpCallout',ex);
            throw ex;
     }
  }

Now the testmethod declares a class to be injected at runtime to handle the callout
// Mock HttpResponseGenerator
private class MockHttpResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock {
    Integer statusCode;
    MockHttpResponseGenerator(Integer statusCode) {this.statusCode = statusCode;}
    public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setBody('{"awsAccountDetails":{"000022444666":{"accountId":"000022444666","sellerOfRecordList":["AWS Inc."]},"073537884685":{"accountId":"073537884685","sellerOfRecordList":["AWS Europe"]}}}');
        res.setStatusCode(this.statusCode);
        return res;
    }
}

and the testmethod injects the MockCallout with a statusCode set in the constructor so you can test 200 and non-200 use cases
// given happy path
MockHttpResponseGenerator mockCallout = new MockHttpResponseGenerator (200);
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class,mockCallout);

// Given queueable
QuoteSorAwsIdQueueable queueable = new QuoteSorAwsIdQueueable(mockAwsAccountIds, mockQuoteAwsAccountRecords);

// when queueable executes
try {
    queueable.execute(null);
    // then asserts
}
catch (...) { assert should not happen }

and in another test method ...,
// given unhappy path
MockHttpResponseGenerator mockCallout = new MockHttpResponseGenerator (500);
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class,mockCallout);

// Given queueable
QuoteSorAwsIdQueueable queueable = new QuoteSorAwsIdQueueable(mockAwsAccountIds, mockQuoteAwsAccountRecords);

// when queueable executes
try {
    queueable.execute(null);
    // then assert should not happen
}
catch (...) { assert that QuoteSorAwsIdException should be thrown }

